# Matplotlib: mixed export to pdf and png

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, export

I create a figure with matplotlib `figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)`, plot various stuff `axes[0,0].pcolormesh(...)` and then export the figure to PDF `figure.savefig('figure.pdf')` or to PNG `figure.savefig('figure.png')`.

I have to use PNG, because the PDF-file would be huge, but this makes the figure labels and other texts *blurry*.

Is there a way to export the figure to PDF -- so that labels, etc. are vector graphics -- but with the plots being exported to PNG within the resulting PDF-file? In short: export to PDF, but plots within that PDF to PNG (for small file sizes).

Comment: There's no `PNG` within `PDF` with matplotlib

Comment: @kinshukdua According to the accepted answer below, there is.

Comment: that's rasterization and not really `PNG` in `PDF` as you put it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the *huge* advantages of Matplotlib over other libraries.  If you do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(500, 500), rasterized=True)
fig.savefig('Test.pdf', dpi=50)
```

The axes and labels will still be vectors, but the `pcolormesh` will be rasterized at 50 dpi.  Of course for publication you should used a higher dpi, but it still is excellent for reducing large data sets.  Note that you will also get aliasing artifacts if you downsample data, so use with caution.

[image: PDF with embedded raster]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it worked this way.